# How can I pass a 2 dimensional javascript array to my spring controller using Json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to pass a 2d array to my spring controller from Jquery using a Json request.

Here is my javascript code. conditionValues (and other parameters) is a multidimesnioal array eg conditionValues = [][]

```
$.getJSON("/SafeSiteLive/common/createTaskWizard/saveTask.json", {
            taskName: $("#taskName").val(),
            taskDescription: $("#taskDescription").val(),
            groupId: $("#approverGroupSelect").val(),
            version: selectedVersion,
            liveVersion: liveVersion,
            questions: questions,
            questionTypes: questionTypes,
            conditionValues: conditionValues,
            conditionTypes: conditionTypes,
            conditionPermits: conditionPermits
}, function (data){
   try {
       dialog.dialog("close");
       getGroups();
    } catch (e) {
        alert("An exception occurred in the script. Error name: " + e.name + ". Error message: " + e.message);
    }
});
```

Then in my controller I have

```
@RequestMapping("common/createTaskWizard/saveTask.json")
public void saveTask(
        @RequestParam("taskName") String taskName,
        @RequestParam("taskDescription") String taskDescription,
        @RequestParam("groupId") int approversGroupId,
        @RequestParam("version") int version,
        @RequestParam("liveVersion") int liveVersion,
        @RequestParam("questions[]") String questions[],
        @RequestParam("questionTypes[]") String questionTypes[],
        @RequestParam("conditionValues[][]") String conditionValues[][],
        @RequestParam("conditionTypes[][]") String conditionType[][],
        @RequestParam("conditionPermits[][]") int conditionPermits[][]) {

        // rest of function
```

I can pass one dimensional arrays simple by passing it as normal in the jQuery and receiving it with square brackets in the @RequestParam. The same doesn't work for a 2d array. Does anything work?

Heres the network error I get from firebug when trying to pass the json request.

> "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8080/SafeSiteLive/common/createTaskWizard/saveTask.json?taskName=Testing+voltages&taskDescription=Testing+voltages+with+generator+on&groupId=3&version=1&liveVersion=1&questions%5B%5D=Confirm+that+it+is+necessary+for+electrcial+equipment+to+be+live+while+testing%3F&questions%5B%5D=Would+de-energisation+create+hazards+for+others+(e.g.+de-energise+equipment+critical+to+process+safety%2C+warning+systems+etc)%3F&questions%5B%5D=If+%27Yes%27+to+1.2%2C+confirm+that+this+has+been+communicated+to+the+System+Owner%2FArea+Owner+and+adequate+precautions+implemented%3F&questions%5B%5D=Confirm+the+prospective+incident+energy+of+the+system+(cal%2Fcm2)&questionTypes%5B%5D=yesNoNA&questionTypes%5B%5D=yesNoNA&questionTypes%5B%5D=yesNoNA&questionTypes%5B%5D=textInput&conditionValues%5B0%5D%5B%5D=Yes&conditionValues%5B0%5D%5B%5D=NA&conditionValues%5B1%5D%5B%5D=Yes&conditionTypes%5B0%5D%5B%5D=equals&conditionTypes%5B0%5D%5B%5D=equals&conditionTypes%5B1%5D%5B%5D=equals&conditionTypes%5B2%5D%5B%5D=equals&conditionTypes%5B3%5D%5B%5D=equals&conditionPermits%5B0%5D%5B%5D=1&conditionPermits%5B0%5D%5B%5D=1&conditionPermits%5B1%5D%5B%5D=1&conditionPermits%5B2%5D%5B%5D=1&conditionPermits%5B3%5D%5B%5D=1"
>   saveTas...[

Comment: Why not just post a single JavaScript object to a Java Map parameter?  This seems needlessly complex.

Comment: Square brackets don't go into the `@RequestParam` value, that's one thing. Param names in the GET request URL don't have them, do they?